# Ошибка обращения к виджету в MainUIThread (две идентичных ситуации, в одной возникает, в другой нет)

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, kotlin, http

У меня есть два виджета:

```xml
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/debugView"
    android:layout_width="256dp"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activityAuthorization_widgets_responseStatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/activityAuthorization_widgets_login"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activityAuthorization_widgets_inputPassword" />
```

Есть вот такая активность (не законченная):

```
class ActivityAuthorization : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val httpClient = HttpClient()

    private lateinit var debugView: TextView

    private lateinit var inputLogin: TextInputEditText
    private lateinit var inputPassword: TextInputEditText
    private lateinit var buttonLogIn: Button
    private lateinit var showPassword: CheckBox
    private lateinit var responseStatusView: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_authorization)

        supportActionBar?.hide()

        binder()
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
    private fun binder() {
        debugView = findViewById(R.id.debugView)

        inputLogin = findViewById(R.id.activityAuthorization_widgets_inputLogin)
        inputPassword = findViewById(R.id.activityAuthorization_widgets_inputPassword)
        buttonLogIn = findViewById(R.id.activityAuthorization_widgets_login)

        showPassword = findViewById(R.id.activityAuthorization_widgets_showPassword)
        responseStatusView = findViewById(R.id.activityAuthorization_widgets_responseStatus)

        buttonLogIn.setOnClickListener {
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val response: HttpResponse =
                    httpClient.request(
                        URLS.AUTHORIZATION
                    ) {
                        method = HttpMethod.Get
                        url {
                            parameters.append(
                                URLS.AUTHORIZATION_USERNAME,
                                inputLogin.text.toString()
                            )
                            parameters.append(
                                URLS.AUTHORIZATION_PASSWORD,
                                inputPassword.text.toString()
                            )
                        }
                    }

                when (response.status.value) {
                    200 -> completeAuthorization(response.bodyAsText())
                    404 -> userNotFound()
                    else -> unprocessedResponse()
                }
            }
        }

        showPassword.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) inputPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
            else inputPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun completeAuthorization(responseText: String) {
        val responseData = JsonIterator.deserialize(
            responseText,
            ResponsePackets.AC.Authorization.Done::class.java
        )

        try {
            responseData?.apply {
                debugView.text = "id: ${
                    responseData.data.id
                }\ntoken: ${responseData.data.token}"
            } ?: unprocessedResponse()
        } catch (_: NullPointerException) { unprocessedResponse() }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun userNotFound() {
        responseStatusView.text = "123"
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun unprocessedResponse() {
        responseStatusView.text = "123"
    }
}
```

Сервер (Python Django) возвращает одно из трёх (в зависимости от результата)

```
return JsonResponse({
    'status': 'Done',
    'data': {
        'id': id,
        'token': helper.DBOperator.create_token(request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT'), id)
    }
}, status=200)

return JsonResponse({
    'status': 'Refused',
    'reason': 'BadRequest',
    'description': 'UserNotFound'
}, status=404)

return JsonResponse({
    'status': 'Refused',
    'reason': 'BadRequest',
    'description': 'LackOfArguments'
}, status=406)
```

Ну и 429, но я для дебага закомментировал.

Если проходит статус 200 и данные верны (а они верны), то `id` и `token` нормально отображаются. Никакой ошибки не возникает. Но если возвращается что-то кроме 200, то я делаю переход на `unprocessedResponse()` (пока тоже временно) и получаю:

```
2023-10-08 23:03:39.732  5012-5180  AndroidRuntime          com.gct.cl.android                   E  FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-4
                                                                                                    Process: com.gct.cl.android, PID: 5012
                                                                                                    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:11586)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2648)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:27623)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:27623)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:27623)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:27623)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:27623)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:27623)
                                                                                                        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.requestLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:3605)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:27623)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:10904)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6965)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6751)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6703)
                                                                                                        at com.gct.cl.android.ActivityAuthorization.userNotFound(ActivityAuthorization.kt:106)
                                                                                                        at com.gct.cl.android.ActivityAuthorization.access$userNotFound(ActivityAuthorization.kt:23)
                                                                                                        at com.gct.cl.android.ActivityAuthorization$binder$1$1.invokeSuspend(ActivityAuthorization.kt:76)
                                                                                                        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:115)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:103)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
                                                                                                        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@a649923, Dispatchers.IO]
```

Насколько я понял, ошибка возникает из-за попытки обращения к `responseStatusView` из корунтины, которая делает запрос. Но почему тогда я при статусе `GET 200` не получаю аналогичной ошибки? На всякий случай прилагаю классы-паттерны и классы-хранилища:

```
package com.gct.cl.android;


public class ResponsePackets {
    static class AC {
        static class Authorization {
            static class Done {
                String status;

                AuthData data;
            }
            static class ClientError {
                String status;
                String reason;
                String description;
            }
            static class NotFound {
                String status;
                String reason;
                String description;
            }
        }
        static class AuthData {
            long id;
            String token;
        }
    }
}
```

```
package com.gct.cl.android

object URLS {
    const val AUTHORIZATION = "http://192.168.196.60:8082/auth" // Я подключаюсь через прокси
    const val AUTHORIZATION_USERNAME = "username"
    const val AUTHORIZATION_PASSWORD = "password"
}
```

**UDP**
Я перенёс выдачу текста на `debugView`:

```
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private fun completeAuthorization(responseText: String) {
    val responseData = JsonIterator.deserialize(
        responseText,
        ResponsePackets.AC.Authorization.Done::class.java
    )
    try {
        runOnUiThread {
            Thread {
                responseData?.apply {
                    debugView.text = "id: ${responseData.data.id}\ntoken: ${responseData.data.token}"
                } ?: unprocessedResponse()
            }.start()
        }
    } catch (_: NullPointerException) {
        unprocessedResponse()
    }
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private fun userNotFound() {
    debugView.text = "123"
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private fun unprocessedResponse() {
    debugView.text = "123"
}
```

Иии... Всё работает как и ожидалось.

Попробовал сделать:

```
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private fun userNotFound() {
    runOnUiThread {
        Thread {
            debugView.setText(R.string.authorization_widgets_responseStatus_userNotFound.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

Иии... Та же самая ошибка. Код был протестировал на 4-ёх телефонах и двух эмуляторах. Результат везде один и тот же.

Comment: Делайте как положено и не ломайте себе голову. Все может зависеть от контейнера и состояния UI в момент вызова. То что сейчас у вас не падает, не гарантирует что на других версиях Андроид или телефонах не начнет массово падать.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, я не про это. Вопрос - как мне отредактировать текст на втором виджете? Не получается и всё. А нужно.

Comment: А я именно про это. Редактируйте его в UI thread.

Comment: Вот тут много чего интересного.

Don't access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, ПОВТОРЮСЬ, всё сделано по документации, работает с первым виджетом. Второй виджет работает абсолютно так-же, но на нём вылетает ошибка.

Comment: Вот так `runOnUiThread { Thread { ... }.start() }` можете пробовать сколько угодно раз, никогда работать не будет. Какой смысл из потока переходить на UI-поток чтобы снова запустить еще один поток? В какой это документации вы нашли? ПОВТОРЮСЬ, Don't access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja - вы не можете нормально объяснить как решить проблему? Я понял в чём ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По этой ссылке все красиво расписано, как обращаться к UI из любого потока.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads

Замените ваши многослойные конструкции с потоками на

```
debugView.post {
  debugView.text = "id: ${responseData.data.id}\ntoken:${responseData.data.token}"
}
```

и

```
responseStatusView.post {
  responseStatusView.text = "123"
}
```

и можете вызывать этот код из любого потока.